# How to implement High pass audio filter for a wav file in python

Tags: python-3.x, audio, filtering, audio-processing, highpass-filter

I am working on a project related to audio processing and I want to implement a high pass audio filter for some wave files stored in memory and on live speech also. I found some previously asked question here related to my problem but not exactly like

1-> [Python scipy.signal.remez high pass filter design yields strange transfer function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754979/python-scipy-signal-remez-high-pass-filter-design-yields-strange-transfer-functi)

2-> [Python: High Pass FIR Filter by Windowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341566/python-high-pass-fir-filter-by-windowing)

but I am not getting how can I modify the available code for saved audio files and for live speech also .

i have found a piece of code for low pass filter for saved audio file which is working fine but I am unable to find one for high pass filter.

```
    file_input = '3.wav'
            file_output = 'filter.wav'

            cutOffFrequency = 400.0

            def running_mean(x, windowSize):
            cumsum = np.cumsum(np.insert(x, 0, 0))
            return (cumsum[windowSize:] - cumsum[:-windowSize]) / windowSize

            def interpret_wav(raw_bytes, n_frames, n_channels, sample_width, interleaved = True):

                if sample_width == 1:
                    dtype = np.uint8
                elif sample_width == 2:
                    dtype = np.int16
                else:
                    raise ValueError("Only supports 8 and 16 bit audio formats.")

                channels = np.fromstring(raw_bytes, dtype=dtype)

                if interleaved:

                    channels.shape = (n_frames, n_channels)
                    channels = channels.T
                else:

                    channels.shape = (n_channels, n_frames)

                return channels

            with contextlib.closing(wave.open(file_input,'rb')) as spf:
                sampleRate = spf.getframerate()
                ampWidth = spf.getsampwidth()
                nChannels = spf.getnchannels()
                nFrames = spf.getnframes()


                signal = spf.readframes(nFrames*nChannels)
                spf.close()
                channels = interpret_wav(signal, nFrames, nChannels, ampWidth, True)



                freqRatio = (cutOffFrequency/sampleRate)
                N = int(math.sqrt(0.196196 + freqRatio**2)/freqRatio)


                filtered = running_mean(channels[0], N).astype(channels.dtype)

                wav_file = wave.open(file_output, "w")
                wav_file.setparams((1, ampWidth, sampleRate, nFrames, spf.getcomptype(), spf.getcompname()))
                wav_file.writeframes(filtered.tobytes('C'))
                wav_file.close()
```

This is the code I am using for low pass filter .

Comment: It is good that you showed what else you had looked at, but you failed to describe why these did not meet your needs.  Also your code has indenting issues

Comment: That indentation error is not present in my code file as it was generated while pasting code here in the post,

Comment: If the indent errors are left,then it makes it difficult to cut and paste and test it. If you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, it makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: These available solution are generating there own frequency and then applying high pass filter on it, where as I want it to apply on a saved .wav audio file, and further on live speech, that is the part where it is not helping me.

Comment: Sir, here is the code with proper indentation
[Here for code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7BbdaWiBmY9bC13d2ViRHpyUVk)